Full duplex named pipes on Windows
I would like to implement full duplex named pipe communications on Windows.  The server needs to be in C++, and needs to be able to connect to multiple clients simultaneously.  The client  needs to be in C#. The client/server languages are not negotiable, this is part of an existing project.
This is what I have currently as a demo app to try and provide a POC.  This is the C++ server side:
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

// Handle client communication
void handleClientCommunication(HANDLE hPipe) {
    char buffer[512];
    DWORD bytesRead, bytesWritten;
    BOOL result;

    while (true) {
        // Read from client
        result = ReadFile(hPipe, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &bytesRead, NULL);
        if (!result || bytesRead == 0) {
            if (GetLastError() == ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE) {
                std::cout << "Client disconnected." << std::endl;
            } else {
                std::cerr << "ReadFile failed, GLE=" << GetLastError() << std::endl;
            }
            break;
        }

        std::string receivedMessage(buffer, bytesRead);
        std::cout << "Received: " << receivedMessage << std::endl;

        // Echo the message back to the client
        result = WriteFile(hPipe, buffer, bytesRead, &bytesWritten, NULL);
        if (!result || bytesWritten != bytesRead) {
            std::cerr << "WriteFile failed, GLE=" << GetLastError() << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    CloseHandle(hPipe);
}

// Read server input and send messages to client
void readServerInputAndSendMessages(HANDLE hPipe) {
    std::string input;
    DWORD bytesWritten;

    while (true) {
        std::getline(std::cin, input);  // Read input from server's keyboard
        input += '\n';  // Optionally add a newline character
        
        // Send message to client
        BOOL result = WriteFile(hPipe, input.c_str(), input.size(), &bytesWritten, NULL);
        if (!result || bytesWritten != input.size()) {
            std::cerr << "WriteFile failed (sending from server), GLE=" << GetLastError() << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}

// Create named pipe server
void createNamedPipeServer() {
    const std::wstring pipeName = L"\\\\.\\pipe\\MyNamedPipe";
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    while (true) {
        HANDLE hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(
            pipeName.c_str(),             // pipe name
            PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,           // read/write access
            PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE |           // message type pipe
            PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE |       // message-read mode
            PIPE_WAIT,                    // blocking mode
            PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,     // max. instances
            512,                          // output buffer size
            512,                          // input buffer size
            0,                            // client time-out
            NULL);                        // default security attribute

        if (hPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            std::cerr << "CreateNamedPipe failed, GLE=" << GetLastError() << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        std::cout << "Waiting for client connection..." << std::endl;
        BOOL connected = ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL) ? TRUE : (GetLastError() == ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED);

        if (connected) {
            std::cout << "Client connected, creating communication threads." << std::endl;

            // Start thread to handle client communication
            std::thread clientThread(handleClientCommunication, hPipe);
            clientThread.detach();

            // Start thread to read server input and send messages to client
            std::thread inputThread(readServerInputAndSendMessages, hPipe);
            inputThread.detach();
        } else {
            CloseHandle(hPipe);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    createNamedPipeServer();
    return 0;
}

This is the C# client:
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PipeClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (NamedPipeClientStream pipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "MyNamedPipe", PipeDirection.InOut, PipeOptions.Asynchronous))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connecting to server...\n");
                pipeClient.Connect();

                CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

                // Start sending and receiving tasks
                Task sendTask = Task.Run(() => SendMessages(pipeClient, cts.Token));
                Task receiveTask = Task.Run(() => ReceiveMessages(pipeClient, cts.Token));

                Task.WhenAny(sendTask, receiveTask).Wait();

                // Cancel the other task and wait for it to complete
                cts.Cancel();
                Task.WaitAll(new[] { sendTask, receiveTask }, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("closed pipe");
        }

        static async Task SendMessages(NamedPipeClientStream pipeClient, CancellationToken token)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pipeClient))
            {
                sw.AutoFlush = true;

                while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    Console.Write("Enter message (or 'exit' to quit): ");
                    string message = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (message == "exit")
                        break;

                    await sw.WriteLineAsync(message);
                }
            }
        }

        static async Task ReceiveMessages(NamedPipeClientStream pipeClient, CancellationToken token)
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeClient))
            {
                while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string response = await sr.ReadLineAsync();
                        if (response == null)
                            break;

                        Console.WriteLine("Received from server: " + response);
                    }
                    catch (IOException)
                    {
                        break; // Exit the loop if the pipe is closed
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Everything is working as intended, (though I have not tested multiple clients, I am sure that will need more work), except the server won't send a message unless it first receives one from the client. The message from the server seems to be cached till the client initiates a connection, then the 'cached' data is returned along with the echoed response from the clients message.
I am trying to figure out if the issue is indeed a stream caching issue that can be resolved, or if my whole named pipe connection method is flawed.
I have discovered that if I use two pipes, one for each direction, I can get closer to my goal, but there's still some issues with this approach as well.
C++ server:
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

const std::wstring pipeNameFromClient = L"\\\\.\\pipe\\PipeFromClient";
const std::wstring pipeNameToClient = L"\\\\.\\pipe\\PipeToClient";

// Handle client communication for receiving messages from client
void receiveMessagesFromClient(HANDLE hPipeFromClient) {
    char buffer[512];
    DWORD bytesRead, bytesWritten;
    BOOL result;

    while (true) {
        // Read from client
        result = ReadFile(hPipeFromClient, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &bytesRead, NULL);
        if (!result || bytesRead == 0) {
            if (GetLastError() == ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE) {
                std::cout << "Client disconnected." << std::endl;
            } else {
                std::cerr << "ReadFile failed, GLE=" << GetLastError() << std::endl;
            }
            break;
        }

        std::string receivedMessage(buffer, bytesRead);
        std::cout << "Received from client: " << receivedMessage << std::endl;

        // Echo the message back to the client
        HANDLE hPipeToClient = CreateFile(
            pipeNameToClient.c_str(),        // pipe name
            GENERIC_WRITE,                  // write access
            0,                              // no sharing
            NULL,                           // default security attributes
            OPEN_EXISTING,                  // opens existing pipe
            0,                              // default attributes
            NULL);                          // no template file

        if (hPipeToClient == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            std::cerr << "CreateFile failed, GLE=" << GetLastError() << std::endl;
            break;
        }

        result = WriteFile(hPipeToClient, buffer, bytesRead, &bytesWritten, NULL);
        if (!result || bytesWritten != bytesRead) {
            std::cerr << "WriteFile failed, GLE=" << GetLastError() << std::endl;
            CloseHandle(hPipeToClient);
            break;
        }

        CloseHandle(hPipeToClient);
    }

    CloseHandle(hPipeFromClient);
}

// Handle client communication for sending messages to client
void sendMessagesToClient(HANDLE hPipeToClient) {
    std::string input;
    DWORD bytesWritten;

    while (true) {
        std::getline(std::cin, input);  // Read input from server's keyboard
        input += '\n';  // Optionally add a newline character

        // Send message to client
        BOOL result = WriteFile(hPipeToClient, input.c_str(), input.size(), &bytesWritten, NULL);
        if (!result || bytesWritten != input.size()) {
            std::cerr << "WriteFile failed (sending to client), GLE=" << GetLastError() << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}

// Create named pipe server for client to server communication
void createNamedPipeFromClient() {
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    while (true) {
        HANDLE hPipeFromClient = CreateNamedPipe(
            pipeNameFromClient.c_str(),     // pipe name
            PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,             // read/write access
            PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE |             // message type pipe
            PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE |         // message-read mode
            PIPE_WAIT,                      // blocking mode
            PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,       // max. instances
            512,                            // output buffer size
            512,                            // input buffer size
            0,                              // client time-out
            NULL);                          // default security attribute

        if (hPipeFromClient == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            std::cerr << "CreateNamedPipe (from client) failed, GLE=" << GetLastError() << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        std::cout << "Waiting for client (from client) connection..." << std::endl;
        BOOL connected = ConnectNamedPipe(hPipeFromClient, NULL) ? TRUE : (GetLastError() == ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED);

        if (connected) {
            std::cout << "Client (from client) connected, creating communication threads." << std::endl;

            // Start thread to receive messages from client (from client)
            std::thread receiveThread(receiveMessagesFromClient, hPipeFromClient);
            receiveThread.detach();
        } else {
            CloseHandle(hPipeFromClient);
        }
    }
}

// Create named pipe server for server to client communication
void createNamedPipeToClient() {
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    while (true) {
        HANDLE hPipeToClient = CreateNamedPipe(
            pipeNameToClient.c_str(),       // pipe name
            PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,             // read/write access
            PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE |             // message type pipe
            PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE |         // message-read mode
            PIPE_WAIT,                      // blocking mode
            PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,       // max. instances
            512,                            // output buffer size
            512,                            // input buffer size
            0,                              // client time-out
            NULL);                          // default security attribute

        if (hPipeToClient == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            std::cerr << "CreateNamedPipe (to client) failed, GLE=" << GetLastError() << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        std::cout << "Waiting for client (to client) connection..." << std::endl;
        BOOL connected = ConnectNamedPipe(hPipeToClient, NULL) ? TRUE : (GetLastError() == ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED);

        if (connected) {
            std::cout << "Client (to client) connected, creating communication threads." << std::endl;

            // Start thread to send messages to client (to client)
            std::thread sendThread(sendMessagesToClient, hPipeToClient);
            sendThread.detach();
        } else {
            CloseHandle(hPipeToClient);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    // Create server threads for both pipes
    std::thread fromClientThread(createNamedPipeFromClient);
    std::thread toClientThread(createNamedPipeToClient);

    fromClientThread.join();
    toClientThread.join();

    return 0;
}

C# client
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PipeClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Connect to the named pipes on the server
            using (NamedPipeClientStream pipeToServer = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "PipeFromClient", PipeDirection.Out, PipeOptions.Asynchronous))
            using (NamedPipeClientStream pipeFromServer = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "PipeToClient", PipeDirection.In, PipeOptions.Asynchronous))
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Connecting to server...");

                    // Connect to the pipes
                    await pipeToServer.ConnectAsync();
                    await pipeFromServer.ConnectAsync();

                    Console.WriteLine("Connected to server.\n");

                    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

                    // Start sending and receiving tasks
                    Task sendTask = Task.Run(() => SendMessages(pipeToServer, cts.Token));
                    Task receiveTask = Task.Run(() => ReceiveMessages(pipeFromServer, cts.Token));

                    Task.WhenAny(sendTask, receiveTask).Wait();

                    // Cancel the other task and wait for it to complete
                    cts.Cancel();
                    Task.WaitAll(new[] { sendTask, receiveTask }, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Closed pipes.");
        }

        static async Task SendMessages(NamedPipeClientStream pipeToServer, CancellationToken token)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pipeToServer))
            {
                sw.AutoFlush = true;

                while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    Console.Write("Enter message (or 'exit' to quit): ");
                    string message = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (message == "exit")
                        break;

                    await sw.WriteLineAsync(message);
                }
            }
        }

        static async Task ReceiveMessages(NamedPipeClientStream pipeFromServer, CancellationToken token)
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeFromServer))
            {
                while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string response = await sr.ReadLineAsync();
                        if (response == null)
                            break;

                        Console.WriteLine("Received from server: " + response);
                    }
                    catch (IOException)
                    {
                        break; // Exit the loop if the pipe is closed
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

While this approach mostly works, the server-client pipe is periodically closed, and I haven't been able to figure out why.
This SO post contains some conflicting opinions whether asynchronous full duplex named pipe communications is feasible with only one pipe. I'm not sure which method I should focus on, but I would like to be able to use only one pipe.

Do you give any input to the "server" that it can write to the client?

And there's a possible data-race when your two threads can write to the pipe simultaneously. I don't know how Windows handle it, but it's generally not a good idea.

I am currently not providing any indication to the server that it can write.  I want to be open to two way communications at all times.
I thought I was safe from a data race condition by passing the same handle to both threads, but I could be wrong there.

According to Named Pipes: A named pipe is a named, one-way or duplex pipe for communication between the pipe server and one or more pipe clients. All instances of a named pipe share the same pipe name, but each instance has its own buffers and handles, and provides a separate conduit for client/server communication. The use of instances enables multiple pipe clients to use the same named pipe simultaneously. There are additional URLS at the bottom of the referenced article that may be helpful.
